# Apple Watch Font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What font does Apple Watch use for the time and other information presented in number form? I looked this up but the only one I could find was the San Fransisco one. However, the SF one is not rounded enough. I tried WhatTheFont, but it couldn't identify it. Thank you for any help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you please follow the [guidelines for asking font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions). Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr - in this particular instance, the font is searchable by quite a simple route ( + I already knew ;) so I dropped in an answer.

Comment: @MantasViazmitinas - my comment was to get you to tell us what you tried to do to find the font yourself. When I commented - you hadn't mentioned that you had tried whatthefont.  You have done so now. That's all you had to do!

Comment: @MantasViazmitinas Maybe try to have a little less yelling caps when you're asking people to help you out. We're doing you a favor here, not the other way around. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watchOS uses SF Compact, part of Apple's San Fransisco family.

It is not licensed for use outside watchOS & is limited to development for that OS only.

Ref: Wikipedia - [San Francisco (sans-serif typeface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(sans-serif_typeface))

*Late Edit:*
After [many] comments &  further research...
Actually, I think you might be out of luck - that font is not SF Compact & **is not** the watchOS font. You only see it on early "photos" or possibly mockups of the  Watch v1.
If it is an Apple font, it may never have left the building.

Comment: Actually, I think you might be out of luck - that font is not SF Compact & **is not** the watchOS font. You only see it on early "photos" or possibly mockups of the  Watch v1.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's [SF Compact Rounded](https://developer.apple.com/design/downloads/SF-Font-Compact.dmg) from Apple's [Fonts](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) page.

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: Updated link

Comment: When suggesting a font please make sure to include a screenshot of that font.